# href issues - linking to a page within a subfolder on a landing page

Tags: html, node.js, anchor, href

Using node.js.

On my landing.ejs page, I am trying to create an href link to an .ejs page within a subfolder of my 'views' directory.

My landing.ejs page is within my 'views' directory. I also have a separate subfolder in my 'views' directory called 'rNotes', that has an JPark.ejs page.

I have set my views engine to ejs.

here is what I have-

```
<h1>
    Landing Page
</h1>

<P>
    Hold on to your butts!
</P>

<a href="rNotes/JPark">View Jurassic Park</a>
```

I have tried:

```
<a href="./rNotes/JPark">View JPark</a>
<a href="../rNotes/JPark">View JPark</a>
<a href="/views/rNotes/JPark">View JPark</a>
```

Comment: What happens with the attempts you made? Are you sure you added the path reference to your serverjs? Something like `app.get('/rNotes/JPark', function(req, res) {
    res.render('views/JPark');
});` or whatever?

Comment: Thanks Chris - yes, in my app.js file I have app.get("/rNotes/JPark", function (req,res){ res.render("/rNotes/JPark");                                                                                                the error I get is  -  Error: Failed to lookup view "/rNotes/lGrowth" in views directory "/xx/xx/jurassicPark/views"

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you.